# What are the steps to secure permission from real people?

Tags: legal

I want to write a novel where the main character is a real person, someone famous.
What are the steps to ask permission to do so?
Who do I have to contact? (like the person's agent, lawyer, etc.)

Comment: Check the related links. This question has been asked before. –––>

Comment: What jurisdiction do you live in?  Is the work you plan fictional?

Comment: Jurisdiction US, the novel is totally fictional, with real people being themselves in the story.

Answer (score 1):

Start with your IP lawyer and make sure you do everything required the correct way.

But why?   What will you do when they say no?   Why should they say yes when they have no idea how your novel will actually portray them?

If it is an incidental use you may not need permission.   You need to start with your IP lawyer.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm aware they would need to read the finished story, which is almost done. I just want to know what the usual the procedure might be, maybe reference to novels written this way recently. Saying talk to your lawyer is a bit stating the obvious.